# how delete architecture in flutter apk

Tags: flutter, dart, visual-studio-code

I'm making an app on flutter(i'm a rookie on this language), and i see on the lib folder of the app 6 architectures `x86`, `x86_64`, `mips`, `armeabi`, `armeabi-v7a`, `arm64_v8a` but to upload on the playstore just need 2 `armeabi-v7a` and `arm64_v8a`. my question is, how can i compile the app without the other 4 architectures to reduce the size of the app because with the 6 folders it is 140MB?

p/s: English is not my natural lenguaje

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you're only doing `flutter build` hence, you're getting so many builds.

Here's what you can do,

- if you're building for a play store, the recommended way to do is by building an `appBundle` which you can refer how to [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/bundletool#generate_apks)
- you can try `flutter build apk --split-per-abi` which will produce only 3 versions `arm64-v8a`, `armeabi-v7a` and `x86` so you can extract the two and upload.
- Additionally, you can build for only specific platforms by using this command

`flutter build apk --target-platform android-arm64,android-arm --split-per-abi`

refer [this](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/configure-apk-splits#configure-abi-split) for more information on splitting.

Comment: hi, thanks for answer. I try ```flutter build apk --split-per-abi``` but it make an apk for every architecture, but i need the app have ```arm64-v8a``` y ```armeabi-v7a``` in the same apk

Comment: @SerNocturno, I've updated the answer. Check it out now it should work

Comment: i try  again but it generate again an apk per architecture [here's the result](https://ibb.co/xmqjqGp)

Comment: @SerNocturno, It worked for me, can you please do `flutter clean` and then try the last command again? It will build only a single apk for the platform you want.

Comment: sorry is the same, i don't know why. i reinstall flutter sdk but the build compile each architecture on an apk, there is a config or something that i have to change

Answer (score 0):

in ../android/app/build.gradle add the lines

```
android {
   ...
   defaultConfig {
       ...  
       ndk {
          abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", "arm64-v8a"
       }
   }
}
```

built for all architectures by default